# trying to understand the whole progress of php scripts running

Tags: php

I am trying to understand the whole progress of php scripts running. such as analyze,compile,... I googled online, but did not find good article about it. So any explanation or documentation? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is a scripting language, and doesn't compile before running.

Pretty much everything you would ever want to know can be found at http://www.php.net

It really is good documentation, give it a go.